# How to convert if else condition to numpy in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
TN=FN=FP=TP=0
for j in range(0,len(data)):   
  
    if((data['y'][j]==0) & (data['proba'][j]==0)):
        TN+=1
    elif((data['y'][j]==0) & (data['proba'][j]==1)):
        FN+=1
    elif((data['y'][j]==1) & (data['proba'][j]==0)):
        FP+=1
    elif((data['y'][j]==1) & (data['proba'][j]==1)):
        TP+=1
```

when i tried  to use above code by using numpy mentioned below i am getting error,
can any one suggest how to use above code by using numpy.

```
for j in range(0,len(data_auc.y_bar)):
        np.where((data_auc['y'][j] == 0) & (data_auc['ypred'][j] == 0), TN+=1,TN+=0)
        np.where((data_auc['y'][j] == 0) & (data_auc['ypred'][j] == 1), FN+=1,FN+=0)
        np.where((data_auc['y'][j] == 1) & (data_auc['ypred'][j] == 0), FP+=1,FP+=0)
        np.where((data_auc['y'][j] == 1) & (data_auc['ypred'][j] == 1), TP+=1,TP+=0)
```

```
File "<ipython-input-9-eec3f903a254>", line 14
    np.where((data_auc['y'][j] == 0) & (data_auc['ypred'][j] == 0), TN+=1:TN+=0)
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: (Re)read the documentation for `np.where`.  It is not a simple if/else substitute.  It's a **function** that takes 3 arguments (arrays).  As with all python functions, those arguments are evaluated before being passed to the function.  In other words, this is standard python syntax, not some thing new.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using a binary and (&) instead of a logical (`and`),

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the beginning and think about what this code really does:

```
TN=FN=FP=TP=0
```

OK, so we have four integers.

```
for j in range(0,len(data)):
```

We loop over all the rows.  Notice that the next parts are all independent and similar so I'm only going to discuss one of them.

```
    if((data['y'][j]==0) & (data['proba'][j]==0)):
        TN+=1
```

When the loop is complete, TN will be the *count of rows* where `y` is 0 and `proba` is 0.  We can therefore eliminate the loop like this:

```
TN = ((data['y']==0) & (data['proba']==0)).sum()
```

Do that three more times for the other three variables, and you'll have code which is at least 10x faster.